# Javascript Remove all unicode exept smily unicode

Tags: javascript

In javascript I want to remove all unicode or non english characters. But I want to keep emoji unicode..and i need work emoji any one have any idea?

```
 msg = msg .replace(/[\r\n]|[^a-zA-Z0-9\!\?\;\:\$\#\@\*\%\,\'\"\<\>\+\(\)\.\-\_]/g, ' ');
```

This code removes all non english character also it removes smily unicode. how can i keep smily unicode
i used https://github.com/danbovey/EmojiPanel for emojis.

Comment: pls can u explain with code ..i need add all emojis like u told?

Comment: adding emiji one by one its work but if i add +emojiString+ its not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex to keep emojis and ascii english characters, and remove everything else: `/[\r\n]|[^\uD83C-\uDFFFa-zA-Z0-9\!\?\;\:\$\#\@\*\%\,\'\"\<\>\+\(\)\.\-\_]/g`. For example:

```js
$("#test").click(function() {
  var msg = $('.foo').text();
  msg = msg.replace(/[\r\n]|[^\uD83C-\uDFFFa-zA-Z0-9\!\?\;\:\$\#\@\*\%\,\'\"\<\>\+\(\)\.\-\_]/g, '');
  $('.foo').text(msg);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">あいうえおかがきぎくぐけこさざしじすせそただちぢつてとなにぬねのはばぱひふへほまみむ test あいうえおかがきぎくぐけこさざしじすせそただちぢつてとなにぬねのはばぱひふへほまみむ</div>
<button id="test">remove non ascii except for emoji</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

this code remove non english characters

```js
str="hi سلام 嗨 नमस्ते";
str.replace(/[^\u0000-\u024F]+/g, "");
```

Comment: ok; Please test the following code `str.replace(/([^\u1f600-\u1f1ff])/g,'')`